# react.js how to display multiple error messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I just got started to react so please bear with me. I don't know exactly what I am doing, I'm just picking those things as I go so I'll do my best to walk you through my mental process when building this.

My intentions are to create a registration component, where the backend returns the validation errors in case there are any in form of an object which has following structure.

```js
{
    "username": [
        "A user with that username already exists."
    ],
    "email": [
        "A user is already registered with this e-mail address."
    ]
}
```

The state manager that I chose to be using is `redux`, so this comes back every time when the register function is dispatched.

Since it has this structure I wrote a function to help me decompose it and pick up only on the actual errors (the strings).

```js
    const walkNestedObject = (obj, fn) => {
        const values = Object.values(obj)

        values.forEach(val =>
            val && typeof val === "object" ? walkNestedObject(val, fn) : fn(val))
    }
```

now I want to display them in the view, so I wrote another function which is supposed to do that

```js
    const writeError = (value) => {
        return <Alert message={value} type="error" showIcon />
    }
```

Down in the actual component I am calling it as this:

```js
{(props.error) ? walkNestedObject(props.error, writeError) : null}
```

To my surprise if I `console.log` the value above return in `writeError` it works flawlessly, every single error gets printed, but none of them gets rendered.

To debug this I've tried multiple variations and none of them seemed to work, I even called the `writeError` function in the component as

```
{writeError('test')}
```

and it worked for some reason.

At this stage I'm just assuming there's some react knowledge required to fulfil this task that Im just now aware of.

EDIT:
A mock example can be found over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssf6ou?file=Hello.js)
Also, I've tried using the first two answers and when mapping through the errors I get this

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.error.map is not a function
```

with other variations, it mentions the promise from so I'd include how I manage the API request

```js
export const authSignup = (username, email, password1, password2) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/', {
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password1: password1,
        password2: password2
    })
        .then(res => {
            const token = res.data.key;
            const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
            dispatch(authSuccess(token));
            dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(authFail(err.response.data))
        })
}
```

Comment: a minimal working example on stackblitz will make it easier to help

Comment: it looks kinda horrible and I had to improvise the backend response but hopefully you ll get it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssf6ou?file=Hello.js

Comment: Where are you using `props.error`?  I can't find it anywhere in your code

Comment: I get it from redux with mapstatetoprops. Ive taken that away in the mock

Comment: I'm playing with your stackblitz but I'm really struggling to understand how the errors are collected.  I don't see any function that runs on submission of the form or anything...how is your list of errors being created?

Comment: does [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Terkea/django_react_template/master/react/src/containers/Signup.js) help?

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the topology of your error messages:

```
"errors": [
  { "type": "username", "message": "Username already in use." },
  { "type": "email", "message": "Email address already in use."}
]
```

That makes your implementation a bit easier:

```js
// MyLogin.jsx
import React from 'react'

const MyLogin = () => {
  /**
   * Here we're using state hooks, since it's much simpler than using Redux.
   * Since we don't need this data to be made globally available in our
   * application, it doesn't make sense to use Redux anyway.
   */
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState([])

  const handleLogin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post('/api/login', formData).then(() => successAction(), (error: any) => {
      setErrors(error) // Update our local state with the server errors
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      {errors.length && ( // Conditionally render our errors
        errors.map((error) => (
          <Alert type={error.type} message={error.message} />
        )
      )}
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <input type='text' name='email' />
        <input type='text' name='username' />
        <input type='password' name='password' />
      </form>
    <>
  )
}

export default MyLogin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `walkNestedFunction` function checks each layer of an object, and if a given layer of the object is an object itself, it then uses *that* object to run your function - which in this case is `writeError`.  `writeError` returns an error `<Alert />` as soon as an error arises.  But when you stick `writeError` inside the circular logic of `walkNestedFunction`, it will hit the first `return` statement, render it to the page, and then stop rendering.  I think this is why you're getting the complete list of errors logged to the console.  Your `walkNestedFunction` continues cycling down through object layers until its done.  But in React, only the first `return` statement will actually render.

A better tactic would be to modify your `writeError` function to record the erors to a state variable.  Then you can render this state variable.  Every time the state is updated, the component will rerender with the updated state.

```
// Define state in your component to contain an array of errors:

state = {
  errors: []
}

// Add an error into state with each iteration of writeError

const writeError = (error) => {
  this.setState({
    errors: [
      ...this.state.errors,
      error
    ]
  })
}


// inside render(), render the state variable containing your errors

<div>
  { this.state.errors.map(error => <p>error</p>) }
</div>
```

`